# how to know file URL in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to create a function to receive payment notifications (callbacks) from banks in Zend Framework.

Banks need a URL to send payment notifications.

I'm having trouble determining the URL Path of the function I created. In order to be hit by the bank.

I created a function here:

```
/app/backend/scripts/payment.php
```

I want the URL to be like this:

```
http://example.com/app/backend/scripts/payment.php

this not working....maybe this URL is wrong
```

how to get the correct URL?

Comment: It's just like creating any other publicly accessible page/url in your application. How have you set those up? Also, can you expand on "not working"? Have you tried to debug what actually happens? Some banks tells you what error they got when they tried.

Comment: this is still in the development stage...not yet integrated with the bank. The url when hit with a 404 error. maybe the URL is wrong. I'm new using zend. If in Codeigniter usually use Base_URL.

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a look at [zend/laminas tutorial](https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/overview/), specifically at the [routing paragraph](https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/routing-and-controllers/). Even if you didn't explicitly specified which zend version you are using, I sincerly hope you are using the last one (which now is called "Laminas")